# PDF.js opens pdf in Firefox but not Chrome/Chromium or Extension

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-chrome-extension

I am just trying to get a simple test of pdf.js to run to test it's basic functionality and using the following code it displays fine in Firefox but not in any Chrome browser or Chrome extension which is where I really need it(Chrome Extension). I am just grabbing a pdf locally to display with PDF.js. Any suggestions?

```
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <button id="prev" onclick="goPrevious()">Previous</button>
    <button id="next" onclick="goNext()">Next</button>
    &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <span>Page: <span id="page_num"></span> / <span id="page_count"></span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
  </div>

  <!-- Use latest PDF.js build from Github -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    //
    // NOTE: 
    // Modifying the URL below to another server will likely *NOT* work. Because of browser
    // security restrictions, we have to use a file server with special headers
    // (CORS) - most servers don't support cross-origin browser requests.
    //
    var url = '/home/brent/Documents/pdfviewer/custodian-parent.pdf';

    //
    // Disable workers to avoid yet another cross-origin issue (workers need the URL of
    // the script to be loaded, and currently do not allow cross-origin scripts)
    //
    PDFJS.disableWorker = true;

    var pdfDoc = null,
        pageNum = 1,
        scale = 1.0,
        canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //
    // Get page info from document, resize canvas accordingly, and render page
    //
    function renderPage(num) {
      // Using promise to fetch the page
      pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        var renderContext = {
          canvasContext: ctx,
          viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
      });

      // Update page counters
      document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = pageNum;
      document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;
    }

    //
    // Go to previous page
    //
    function goPrevious() {
      if (pageNum <= 1)
        return;
      pageNum--;
      renderPage(pageNum);
    }

    //
    // Go to next page
    //
    function goNext() {
      if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages)
        return;
      pageNum++;
      renderPage(pageNum);
    }

    //
    // Asynchronously download PDF as an ArrayBuffer
    //
    PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(_pdfDoc) {
      pdfDoc = _pdfDoc;
      renderPage(pageNum);
    });
  </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

This code was grabbed from the PDF.js github on one of their examples:
[[http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-prevnext-v2/6748/edit][1]](http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-prevnext-v2/6748/edit%5d%5b1%5d)

Even on their example it does not run In Chrome.

Comment: Chrome's XHR cannot handle file resources. Use local web server when you develop a web application for Chrome that uses XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: You mean just create a web server and have the pdf on it? Then from the chrome extension grab it using a XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: PDF.js and files must be on the same web server (see https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-xhr)

Comment: Also the extension's access to the 'file://' scheme as determined by the user-controlled 'Allow access to File URLs' checkbox

Comment: @async5 You should compile an answer out of your advice, since now it looks like the question has no activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome's XHR cannot handle file resources. Use local web server when you develop a web application for Chrome that uses XMLHttpRequest. PDF.js and files must be on the same web server due to CORS.

Also the extension's access to the 'file://' scheme is determined by the user-controlled 'Allow access to File URLs' checkbox.